# jqGrid - refreshing grid issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am having trouble refreshing the grid on a submit to allow the new data to be shown and then adding a new item again.

The code to explain

jqGrid itself

```
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: List,
        width: 1405,
        shrinkToFit: 1105,
        rowNum: List.length,
        colNames: ['id', 'Delete'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', editable: false, hidden: false, hidedlg: true },
            {
                name: 'actions', index: 'actions', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: imageFormat,
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    editbutton: false,
                    delOptions: { url: getURL('controller') + 'actionmethod?id=' + $('#id').val() }
                }

            }
        ],
```

An external button to add a row

```
$("#Add").click(function () {

   $("#grid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { height: 480, width: 400, reloadAfterSubmit: true, recreateForm: true });

});
```

And basically the afterSubmit event...

```
$("#grid").bind("AfterSubmit", function (event, status, postData) {

    $("#grid").jqGrid('GridUnload');

    // This basically calls the code on the top       
    loadGrid();

   // close the add item dialog...
});
```

The problem is:

if I remove the line: `$("#grid").jqGrid('GridUnload')`

The grid will not refresh correctly (doesnt add the new row on the UI) however, it will add it to the database on the server end and I can keep adding new rows successfully to the database but without no refresh.

*When I say, "it will add it to the database" I mean if I reload the whole page, the items will show*

If I keep the line: `$("#grid").jqGrid('GridUnload')`

The grid will refresh properly on **the first time only** and add the row into the database. Afterwards I can keep adding but the submit window doesnt close nor do the grid refresh.

I have tried using

`$("#grid").trigger('gridReload')` - but without any success (maybe I a using it wrong)

Thanks

Comment: @oleg - Apparently your the man to call with these jqGrid issues. If I have done this wrong (commenting your name in the question) I apologise

Comment: can you post jsfiddle ?

Comment: Probably not as its not all my code.

Comment: do you use firebug if yes please check whether you are getting any js errors in console tab after grid refreshes first time but not for subsequent insertions.

Comment: Good idea, will have a look thanks, @AtulNar

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake in here:

> I have tried using
>
> $("#grid").trigger('gridReload') - but without any success (maybe I a
>   using it wrong)

The method is "reloadGrid", so using

```
$("#grid").trigger('reloadGrid')
```

should be fine for you needs to refresh the grid data only.

Comment: Thanks for the spot, but it doesn't actually do anything (but it should..) do I need to put in anything after?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste mistake, corrected it.
If this does not triggers the data reload, check the js console for errors, or check the URL monitor if the URL is correct or if the server returns correct response code (200 or similar).